Emag marketplace API read product offer filter not working
I have problem with the emag marketplace api-3, when trying to read a product offer for id=33 product.
The filter is not working in the curl process.
Here is my code:
$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://marketplace.emag.hu/api-3/product_offer/read?id=33');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'email@address.hu'.":".'pass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode('email@address.hu'.":".'pass'),'Content-Type: application/json')); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print($result);

what do you think, what is the solution for my problem?
the code will return all line, not specific to my 33 id product.
i try to change the get customrequest to post, with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

I also had this problem with filtering when I tried to get one order by id! The problem was that I used query parameters and not form-data in the body.
In the documentation I have not found where it mentions to use form-data, it's just says 'parameter'.
Docs: https://marketplace.emag.hu/infocenter/en/emag-academy/api-documentation/
Try this:
curl --location 'https://marketplace.emag.hu/api-3/product_offer/read' \
--header 'Authorization: ••••••' \
--form 'id="123"'

I hope it will help!

Dear Istvan,Thanks a lot! It's working. :)
